# How to properly operate a dynamic hyperlink in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I just put the below command in index.html.rb file,

```
<%=stackoverflow.link%>
```

I can see google.com

But if I put this value in the hyper link,

```
<a href="<%=stackoverflow.link %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">I don't know why</a></br>
```

the result is =>

```
http://localhost:3000/home/www.google.com
```

My root route in routes.rb file is

```
root to: "home#front"
```

I don't know where I'm stuck. The stackoverflow.link is a variable depending on the database. So I want to use a dynamic hyper link. I'm looking forward to seeing some opinions!! :)

Comment: what happens if stackoverflow.link = `https://www.google.com` ?

Comment: yes! If I put https://www.google.com, it works!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your anchor tag seems to be written correctly. However, because your `stackoverflow.link` variable is outputting `www.google.com`, it's being appended to the current request URI. Instead try setting your `stackoverflow.link` variable to `https://www.google.com`. Or, if you have many link entries in your database without protocols and don't wish to go through all of them and prepend it, you can do something like:

```
<a href="<%= 'https://' + stackoverflow.link %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">I don't know why</a>
```

By adding the `https://` the browsers will understand that this link is meant to be external - it will be treated as an absolute path rather than a relative one.

Hope this helps!